numpy linalg matrix rank calculator is wrong?
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank
for i in range(1, 70):
  y = np.linspace(0,i, i+1)
  y = 2 ** y
  x = np.ones(i+1)
  matrix = np.stack([x,y])
  print(matrix_rank(matrix))

After 48 I see the rank shifting from 2 to 1. How do I fix this?

2*48 is a huge number. You are dealing with huge numbers and the computation might be unstable

@Onyambu yeah but I can easily solve this by hand doing gaussian elimination. I'd expect it to be smarter and figure out which algo to use

Do the docs explain any of this?  Looks like it just uses svd.  And some sort of tolerance, default or user defined.

Choosing the best algorithm for results to be numerically stable takes time, sometime more time than doing the computation for basic cases which are not unstable. Stable algorithms for that are AFAIK significantly more expensive. Numpy is built to give a reasonable trade-off between speed and numerical stability. Here it seems not very reasonable to me.

I wonder if this makes sense to compute the value in the log space. Here it would mean just not compute y = 2 ** y, which seems to give the same results (you should certainly compute the log of x consequently).

As explained in the comments, numpy uses numerical algorithms which may produce incorrect results due to the instability of the algorithm when used on matrices with extremely large numbers. If you require an exact solution, you can use a symbolic solver, such as sympy. But when using sympy you trade speed for accuracy.
import sympy as smp

for i in range(1, 70):
    M = smp.Matrix([[2**y for y in range(i)],
                    [1]*i]).T
    print(M.rank())

There is a probably a way to write this more efficiently rather than re-creating the i-1 rows every iteration.
